# How to request more than 15 items from NPR RSS feed?

Tags: rss

The rss feed https://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=4473090 lists 15 items. Is it possible to request more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `numResults` parameter to specify the number of results, which appears to max at 50 items. To access beyond that many items, you can use the `startNum` parameter to iterate through the results.

Examples:

https://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=4473090&numResults=50

https://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=4473090&startNum=51&numResults=50

Reference: https://www.npr.org/api/inputReference.php